# Using QGS file in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, qgs

I have received files in .qgd and .qgs extensions from a friend who works with QGIS.

Is it possible to use that in ArcMap 10.8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, while people have written converters for ArcMap's proprietary formats into open formats, ArcMap does not support QGIS project files and there is no converter available.